# How can I use OnListItemClickListener using this Search Filtering ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm having trouble using setOnItemClickListener in my listview. Everytime I try, it causes too many errors with fixes that makes the code worse than what I'm intending to do.

This is my code:

```
public class Search extends Activity{
// List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;


// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

// Listview Data
final String products[] = {"Fill in the Blocks", "The Music Bee", "Little Paragon",
"Subway Surfers", "Cytus", "Temple Run", "Clumsy Ninja", "Smash Hit"};

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

// Adding items to listview
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name,        products);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

/**
* Enabling Search Filter
* */
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
// When user changed the Text
Search.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
int arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub       
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
}            
});    
}       
}
```

I want to make the strings in the listview data clickable for my other activities but it won't work. I tried this code:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

 String openClass = adapter.getItem[position];
 if (openClass.equals("Fill in the Blocks")) {
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Fill_in_the_Blocks.class);
   startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
   }
 else if (openClass.equals("The Music Bee")) {
   Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), The_Music_Bee.class);
   startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
   }
 else if (openClass.equals("Little Paragon")) {
   Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Little_Paragon.class);
   startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0);
   }
   }
```

The errors were as follows:
-In the lv.setOnItemClickListener, "The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})"
-In the (new OnItemClickListener(), "OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type"
-In the public void onItemClick(AdapterView, "AdapterView cannot be resolved to a type"
-In the String openClass = adapter.getItem[position];, "getItem cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Have you tried [Debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html) your code?

Comment: I did. Those are the errors I have encountered after doing it. The fixes offered were no help so... yeah. Anyway, it's already answered. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that you got it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the lv.setOnItemClickListener, "The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})"
- In the (new OnItemClickListener(), "OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type"
- In the public void onItemClick(AdapterView, "AdapterView cannot be resolved to a type"

The first 3 errors should disappear by replacing new OnItemClickListener() with

```
new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

and make sure you import:

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
```

The final error:

- In the String openClass = adapter.getItem[position];, "getItem cannot be resolved or is not a field"

You are meant to be calling the getItem method, rather than using array indexing.

replace the line:

```
String openClass = adapter.getItem[position];
```

with

```
String openClass = adapter.getItem(position);
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you man. I really appreciate it. It's for a school project I've been working for the past 2 weeks and I haven't gone anywhere. Awesome!